# CCMenuItem doesn't respond subclassing and adding cctouch methods to CCMenu

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenuitem

I'm making a menu, and I want one of the buttons to respond when user touch it down, so I made a subclass of CCMenu in order to add cctouchbegan method And manage it there.
The problem is that I can make it to respond both things (menuItem & cctouch), is this normal?
is there a way to force it to do both things?
Thank you in advance, let me know if you need me to put some of the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `CCMenu.m` -- it already implements `ccTouchBegan` and sets a selected flag on `CCMenuItem`s.  Your approach is probably not working because you're stealing the messages from your parent class.

Your subclass should call `[super ccTouchBegan...]` first, then check the selected state of the `CCMenuItem`s to determine which button to change visually.

---

EDIT:
Or, even easier! -- Subclass the appropriate `CCMenuItem` subclass (e.g. `CCMenuItemSprite`) and overload the `selected` method from it's default to include your visual alterations:

```
-(void) selected
{
    [super selected];
    //call method to update visuals here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create your own CCLayer subclass, set it's isTouchEnabled property to YES and implement any touch logic you want

Comment: This is my second option, the issue here is that, the layer is already touchable, & that's why I would like to manage from the menu

Comment: CCMenu is hust CCLayer subclass with implemented CCTargetedTouchDelegate methods

Comment: Actually I tried, & it didn't work, it's happening the same issue (or button or ccTouchBegan, never both) 
I finally made it work 'faking' the button as a CCSprite & then, implementing the ccTouchBegan & calling the method from there